# Rails 4 sqlite3 Gem::LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting a

```
Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.
```

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'thin'
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Where else do you specify an adapter? As you can see sqlite3 is excluded from the gemfile. Server restart didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Please check your `database.yml`

Answer (score 1):

Please check your database.yml file . you might have specified the adapter as sqlite.

Comment: Actually, mongoid generates a mongoid.yml, can that be substituted directly for database.yml

Comment: Please see if this helps the page talks about how you remove ActiveRecord from Rails 3 http://two.mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html